# Onnxruntime cross-build for android on windows fails

Tags: android, mingw, onnxruntime

I'm trying to build the lastest version of onnxruntime (1.15.1) on Windows 10.

I got the code from microsofts repo and checked out to rel-1.15.1 branch.

Then I checked my android studio paths/versions and made sure I use ndk version 25 and Sdk version 33.

It shows in onnxruntime's official docs that I should run

```
build.bat --android --android_sdk_path C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android --android_ndk_path C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.0.8775105 --android_abi arm64-v8a --android_api 33 --cmake_generator Ninja
```

on where I coped onnxruntime repo to. Running this results in this error:

```
2023-07-27 13:26:21,882 tools_python_utils [INFO] - flatbuffers module is not installed. parse_config will not be available
2023-07-27 13:26:21,887 build [DEBUG] - Command line arguments:
  --build_dir 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime\\build\Windows' --android --android_sdk_path 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android' --android_ndk_path 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.0.8775105' --android_abi arm64-v8a --android_api 33 --cmake_generator Ninja
2023-07-27 13:26:21,908 build [DEBUG] - Defaulting to running update, build [and test for native builds].
2023-07-27 13:26:21,930 build [INFO] - Build started
2023-07-27 13:26:21,931 util.run [INFO] - Running subprocess in 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime'
  git submodule sync --recursive
Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/eigen'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/emsdk'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/libprotobuf-mutator'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/onnx'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/onnx/third_party/benchmark'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/onnx/third_party/pybind11'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'cmake/external/onnxruntime-extensions'
2023-07-27 13:26:23,297 util.run [DEBUG] - Subprocess completed. Return code: 0
2023-07-27 13:26:23,298 util.run [INFO] - Running subprocess in 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime'
  git submodule update --init --recursive
2023-07-27 13:26:24,714 util.run [DEBUG] - Subprocess completed. Return code: 0
2023-07-27 13:26:24,715 build [INFO] - Generating CMake build tree
2023-07-27 13:26:24,716 util.run [INFO] - Running subprocess in 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime\\build\Windows\Debug'
  'C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE' 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime\cmake' -Donnxruntime_RUN_ONNX_TESTS=OFF -Donnxruntime_GENERATE_TEST_REPORTS=ON '-DPython_EXECUTABLE=C:\Python39\python.exe' '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Python39\python.exe' -Donnxruntime_USE_MIMALLOC=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_PYTHON=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_CSHARP=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_JAVA=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_NODEJS=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_OBJC=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_APPLE_FRAMEWORK=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_DNNL=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_NNAPI_BUILTIN=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_RKNPU=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_LLVM=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_MICROSOFT_INTERNAL=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_VITISAI=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_TENSORRT=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_TENSORRT_BUILTIN_PARSER=ON -Donnxruntime_USE_TVM=OFF -Donnxruntime_TVM_CUDA_RUNTIME=OFF -Donnxruntime_TVM_USE_HASH=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_MIGRAPHX=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_CONTRIB_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_ML_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_RTTI=OFF -Donnxruntime_DISABLE_EXCEPTIONS=OFF -Donnxruntime_MINIMAL_BUILD=OFF -Donnxruntime_EXTENDED_MINIMAL_BUILD=OFF -Donnxruntime_MINIMAL_BUILD_CUSTOM_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_REDUCED_OPS_BUILD=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_LANGUAGE_INTEROP_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_DML=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_WINML=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_MS_EXPERIMENTAL_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_TELEMETRY=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_LTO=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_1902=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_1905=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_1908=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_2002=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ARMNN=OFF -Donnxruntime_ARMNN_RELU_USE_CPU=ON -Donnxruntime_ARMNN_BN_USE_CPU=ON -Donnxruntime_USE_JSEP=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_NVTX_PROFILE=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_TRAINING=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_TRAINING_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_TRAINING_APIS=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_CPU_FP16_OPS=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_NCCL=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_BENCHMARKS=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_ROCM=OFF -DOnnxruntime_GCOV_COVERAGE=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_MPI=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_MEMORY_PROFILE=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_CUDA_LINE_NUMBER_INFO=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_WEBASSEMBLY=OFF -Donnxruntime_BUILD_WEBASSEMBLY_STATIC_LIB=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=ON -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_API_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION_THROWING=ON -Donnxruntime_WEBASSEMBLY_RUN_TESTS_IN_BROWSER=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_THREADS=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_DEBUG_INFO=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_PROFILING=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_LAZY_TENSOR=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_EXTERNAL_CUSTOM_OP_SCHEMAS=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_CUDA_PROFILING=OFF -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_ROCM_PROFILING=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_XNNPACK=OFF -Donnxruntime_USE_CANN=OFF '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.0.8775105\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake' -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-33 -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_MIN_SDK=33 -DCMAKE_TLS_VERIFY=ON -DFETCHCONTENT_QUIET=OFF -DONNX_USE_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=OFF -Dprotobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=OFF -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON -Donnxruntime_PYBIND_EXPORT_OPSCHEMA=OFF -G Ninja -Donnxruntime_ENABLE_MEMLEAK_CHECKER=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug '-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime\\build\Windows/Debug/installed'
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:21 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0104 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime\tools\ci_build\build.py", line 2599, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime\tools\ci_build\build.py", line 2460, in main
    generate_build_tree(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime\tools\ci_build\build.py", line 1369, in generate_build_tree
    run_subprocess(
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime\tools\ci_build\build.py", line 781, in run_subprocess
    return run(*args, cwd=cwd, capture_stdout=capture_stdout, shell=shell, env=my_env)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\build\onnxruntime\tools\python\util\run.py", line 49, in run
    completed_process = subprocess.run(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.EXE', 'C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\build\\onnxruntime\\cmake', '-Donnxruntime_RUN_ONNX_TESTS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_GENERATE_TEST_REPORTS=ON', '-DPython_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Python39\\python.exe', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Python39\\python.exe', '-Donnxruntime_USE_MIMALLOC=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_PYTHON=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_BUILD_CSHARP=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_BUILD_JAVA=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_BUILD_NODEJS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_BUILD_OBJC=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_BUILD_APPLE_FRAMEWORK=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_DNNL=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_NNAPI_BUILTIN=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_RKNPU=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_LLVM=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_MICROSOFT_INTERNAL=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_VITISAI=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_TENSORRT=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_TENSORRT_BUILTIN_PARSER=ON', '-Donnxruntime_USE_TVM=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_TVM_CUDA_RUNTIME=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_TVM_USE_HASH=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_MIGRAPHX=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_DISABLE_CONTRIB_OPS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_DISABLE_ML_OPS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_DISABLE_RTTI=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_DISABLE_EXCEPTIONS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_MINIMAL_BUILD=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_EXTENDED_MINIMAL_BUILD=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_MINIMAL_BUILD_CUSTOM_OPS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_REDUCED_OPS_BUILD=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_LANGUAGE_INTEROP_OPS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_DML=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_WINML=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_BUILD_MS_EXPERIMENTAL_OPS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_TELEMETRY=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_LTO=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_ACL=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_1902=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_1905=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_1908=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_ACL_2002=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_ARMNN=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ARMNN_RELU_USE_CPU=ON', '-Donnxruntime_ARMNN_BN_USE_CPU=ON', '-Donnxruntime_USE_JSEP=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_NVTX_PROFILE=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_TRAINING=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_TRAINING_OPS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_TRAINING_APIS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_CPU_FP16_OPS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_NCCL=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_BUILD_BENCHMARKS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_ROCM=OFF', '-DOnnxruntime_GCOV_COVERAGE=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_MPI=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_MEMORY_PROFILE=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_CUDA_LINE_NUMBER_INFO=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_BUILD_WEBASSEMBLY=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_BUILD_WEBASSEMBLY_STATIC_LIB=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=ON', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_API_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION_THROWING=ON', '-Donnxruntime_WEBASSEMBLY_RUN_TESTS_IN_BROWSER=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_THREADS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_DEBUG_INFO=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY_PROFILING=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_LAZY_TENSOR=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_EXTERNAL_CUSTOM_OP_SCHEMAS=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_CUDA_PROFILING=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_ROCM_PROFILING=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_XNNPACK=OFF', '-Donnxruntime_USE_CANN=OFF', '-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\25.0.8775105\\build\\cmake\\android.toolchain.cmake', '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-33', '-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a', '-DANDROID_MIN_SDK=33', '-DCMAKE_TLS_VERIFY=ON', '-DFETCHCONTENT_QUIET=OFF', '-DONNX_USE_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=OFF', '-Dprotobuf_MSVC_STATIC_RUNTIME=OFF', '-Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON', '-Donnxruntime_PYBIND_EXPORT_OPSCHEMA=OFF', '-G', 'Ninja', '-Donnxruntime_ENABLE_MEMLEAK_CHECKER=ON', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug', '-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\build\\onnxruntime\\\\build\\Windows/Debug/installed']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Looking around the internet I came across a solution telling me to install and check mingw32 installation. I made sure it's installed under c:/ and I have it on my Environment variables.

As far as I know this build uses clang because it uses android studio but I have no idea how to check it or debug it.

How can I solve this?